# Tomcat restart issue

Tags: tomcat, restart

I have configured a Tomcat server auto restart but am frequently getting the below error:

```
Dec 10, 2013 5:30:32 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
**SEVERE**: The web application [/Xyz/Abc] appears to have started a thread named [Timer-0] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
```

And this exception is not letting [tomcat](/questions/tagged/tomcat) restart and hence my application is getting stopped.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Need to know about your configurations asap.

Comment: @Soylent - What configurations do you need to know ?

Comment: You have provided very little information in the question. I think we have a better chance of helping you if you provide more information.  You write "I have configured a Tomcat server"  Are there any details about the configuration you can share with us?

Comment: The above warning will not prevent your web application from stopping. If the thread `Timer-0` is not a "daemon" thread, then it will prevent the JVM from stopping.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think its the exception that stops tomcat from restarting. Your shutdown script doesn't really stop tomcat, it just opens a port on the tomcat server (8005 if you didn't change the default in server.xml), tells it to stop, and then exits. Tomcat might still need a second or two to clean up before it exits as well. So if you do something like `shutdown.sh; startup.sh` in your restart script, the starting tomcat might want to bind to a port that the previous tomcat hasn't released yet. Putting a `sleep 5` between shutdown and startup should resolve that.

This is the code i recently wrote when i had the same problem:

```
instdir=/usr/lib
port=8443
$instdir/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh

tries=0
while netstat -anf inet | grep '\*\.'$port > /dev/null
do
    tries=`expr $tries + 1`
    test $tries -ge 12 && break
    sleep 5
done

if test "$tries" -ge 12
then
    echo "Could not stop tomcat, port $port still in use"
    exit 1
fi
$instdir/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
```

Comment: I have to try this. But I get only error lines in the logs if the restart does not happen properly and the tomcat remains shut down until I restart it manually.

Comment: You're probably right - but possibly, the Timer-0 thread doesn't always get started by the application. So if it gets started, tomcat waits for it to terminate, which causes the delay. If it doesn't get started (because you didnt use the feature of your application that needs it), tomcat doesn't have to wait and exits faster.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix the original problem instead of trying to work-around the symptom. Run your web application and figure out what `Timer-0` is doing. That should indicate where it is being initialized. Find that place and ensure the following:

1. The thread is started with daemon=true
2. The thread is stopped in a `ServletContextListener` or something similar

Realistically, #2 above should be done in the same component that launches the thread (`ServletContextInitializer`, `ServletContextListener`, `Servlet`, etc.).